# use IV to predict and as instrument

Tags: predictive-models, econometrics, instrumental-variables

I have data about a certain trait `X` for a small sample of countries and I'm interested in the relationship of `X` on income per capita `Y`. I also have a strong predictor `Z` of `X`. I have data of `Z` for a large number of countries so I used it to predict `X` for all the countries then I regressed `Y` on the predicted values `X-hat`.

Can I also use `Z` as an instrument for `X-hat` in an IV regression of `Y` on `X-hat`?

Comment: IV has been used frequently in cases where you have measurement error in $X$. Your missing data is an extreme version of that. On the other hand, you would have to make some strong assumptions that the first stage has external validity for the full sample, though I suppose this could be reasonable for some types of missing data.